# Express.js: Undefined request body (base64)

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, express

I'm trying to convert the .xls table to .csv row.

I found the library that helps with such operation, its name [XLSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

As the first step, I encode .xls table to base64 format.

Now I'm trying to send the post request with Postman (with base64 code as the body of the request)

But when I'm trying to `console.log` my `req.body`, I'm receiving undefined. Can you tell me where I could make a mistake in my app?

my **app.js**:

```
const express = require('express');
const dataConverter = require('./inputDataConverter');
const { errorHandler } = require('./../error/error-handler');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const domain = process.env.DOMAIN || '0.0.0.0';

app.post('/convert', dataConverter);
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => next('Invalid request'));

app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Microservice runs on http://${domain}:${port}`);
});
```

**inputDataConverter.js:**

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

  console.log('First console.log ' + req.body);

  const getWorkbook = (data) => {
    let wb = null;

    if (!data.type || data.type === 'base64') {
      wb = XLSX.read(data.body, { type: 'base64' });
    }

    console.log('everything is working');
    return wb;
  };

  const requestData = req.body;
  console.log(requestData);

  getWorkbook(requestData);
};
```

Comment: req.body is usualy defined by some middleware which processes the request body.
You may want to have a look  at body parser https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Answer (score 0):

As Molda said
You may need body parser
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

On new version actually body-parser is embedded to express so you can use that like:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

I really suggest you use express-generator package to generate base Express application
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator

You may find something you may not need
just strip that out